Receiving an error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component
I am trying to protect a couple of pages from logged out users. I'm fairly new to react so this is error is new to me, unsure what I am doing wrong...
This is my App.js
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Navigate,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import CustomNavbar from './components/common/Navbar';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import RegisterPage from './pages/RegisterPage';
import CreateJobPage from './pages/CreateJobPage';
import JobsPage from './pages/JobsPage';
import JobPage from './pages/JobPage';
import DashboardPage from './pages/DashboardPage';
import useAuthentication from './utilities/useAuthentication';

function App() {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useAuthentication();

  return (
    <Router>
      <CustomNavbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
        <Route path="/create-job" element={<CreateJobPage />} />
        <Route path="/jobs" element={<JobsPage />} />
        <Route
          path="/job/:id"
          element={isLoggedIn ? <JobPage /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/dashboard"
          element={isLoggedIn ? <DashboardPage /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

I tried to protect pages with doing authentication on page, but I feel like this way would be better?
userAuthentication.js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const useAuthentication = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null); 
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkLoginStatus = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/check-auth', {
          method: 'GET',
          credentials: 'include',
        });
        if (response.ok) {
          const { message, userData } = await response.json();
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
          setUserData(userData); 
        } else {
          navigate('/login');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error checking authentication:', error);
        navigate('/login');
      }
    };

    checkLoginStatus();
  }, [navigate]);

  return { isLoggedIn, userData }; // Return isLoggedIn and userData
};

export default useAuthentication;

Trying to restrict access to pages where a user should be logged in. Doing it on-page wasn't doing what I expected it to. For example, I make a call to my backend for job details on a certain job so it takes a couple of sections to fetch data - when I tried to check for logged in status, the job would still load in the backend, when done, it would then redirect to login...

The error means what it says, you can use useNavigate and so useAuthentication only in the comps that are children to . Move the whole content of App except Router itself to the nested comp

The App component renders the Router and router/routing context, so it can't itself use anything that requires it. Promote the Router higher up the ReactTree such that App is rendered in its sub-ReactTree.
Example:
App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import {
  Route,
  Routes,
  Navigate,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import CustomNavbar from './components/common/Navbar';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import RegisterPage from './pages/RegisterPage';
import CreateJobPage from './pages/CreateJobPage';
import JobsPage from './pages/JobsPage';
import JobPage from './pages/JobPage';
import DashboardPage from './pages/DashboardPage';
import useAuthentication from './utilities/useAuthentication';

function App() {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useAuthentication();

  return (
    <>
      <CustomNavbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
        <Route path="/create-job" element={<CreateJobPage />} />
        <Route path="/jobs" element={<JobsPage />} />
        <Route
          path="/job/:id"
          element={isLoggedIn ? <JobPage /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/dashboard"
          element={isLoggedIn ? <DashboardPage /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

Wrap App in Router:
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Router>
  <App />
</Router>

Use Protected Routes
Alternatively you could implement protected routes:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(); 

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkLoginStatus = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/check-auth', {
          method: 'GET',
          credentials: 'include',
        });

        const { message, userData } = await response.json();
        setUserData(userData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error checking authentication:', error);
        setUserData(null);
      }
    };

    checkLoginStatus();
  }, []);

  if (userData === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return userData
    ? <Outlet context={{ userData }} />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;

App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Navigate,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import CustomNavbar from './components/common/Navbar';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import RegisterPage from './pages/RegisterPage';
import CreateJobPage from './pages/CreateJobPage';
import JobsPage from './pages/JobsPage';
import JobPage from './pages/JobPage';
import DashboardPage from './pages/DashboardPage';
import ProtectedRoutes from './components/ProtectedRoutes';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <CustomNavbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
        <Route path="/create-job" element={<CreateJobPage />} />
        <Route path="/jobs" element={<JobsPage />} />
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
          <Route path="/job/:id" element={<JobPage />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<DashboardPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

